# Can I develop Android TV app without ADT-1?

Tags: android, android-tv

It can be a silly question but [this statement](https://developer.android.com/tv/adt-1/index.html) seems confusing to me

> The ADT-1 Developer Kit is a streaming media player and game
>   controller designed for running and testing apps built for Android TV.
>   Supplies of ADT-1 are limited and it is intended for developers who
>   are interested in building new apps or extending their existing apps
>   to run on the Android TV platform.
>
> Note: **The ADT-1 kit is not required for building and testing apps for
>   Android TV. You can build apps for TV and test them using an emulator
>   for TV devices.** The Android SDK includes all the software needed to
>   build TV apps and an emulator for running and testing them. For more
>   information, see the Get Started guide for TV apps.

There is no single word about developing on real devices, only ADT-1 and emulator. 
 
Can I develop Android TV app on real device such as NVIDIA Shield TV, Razer Forge TV or just "real" TV like Sony Bravia without ADT-1 kit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This guide](https://developer.sony.com/develop/tvs/android-tv/get-started/), from the Sony developers website, shows the steps to connect a Bravia TV to the ADB shell through a router. The TV must be configured as a developer device (the same way you activate Developer Mode on a phone).

You can also set consoles like the NVIDIA Shield and the Nexus Player in developer mode and connect to them using an USB cable, just like a phone, but use the right cable, as the cable that comes with the Nexus Player is just a power cable and it doesn't transfer data.

So yes, you don't need ADT-1.

Comment: Thank you, I also found simiilar information for Razor Forge.